# Linux arch installing enlightenment just stays same as normal kde

Tags: arch-linux, desktop-environment

So I've installed enlightenment simply with
`sudo pacman -S enlightenment`
But when i restart my pc and select an Enlightenment session it just stays the same as what i had originally, kde. I am hoping to be able to get an environment a bit like[image]

So how would i do this?
So im basically trying to ask how do i setup a Enlightenment desktop environment but be able to switch between that and KDE.

Comment: What login manager are you using? Does it give you a choice of environments to login to before you enter your password?

Comment: @Caleb I am just using a sddm for the display manager and I dont know what login environment im using, i think it might be the default kde one. And yes i do have a selection of desktop environments and when i select a different one it doesnt change it at all

Comment: The login manage gives you a selection of desktop environments to login to? Is Enlightenment in that list? What are the other options? Do none of the options change what environment you ed up it after login?

Comment: @Caleb all the options are available including plasma, enlightenment E16 and so on. But when i chose and login with any of those. It changes nothing

Comment: @Caleb here is a picture of the login corner where the selection of environments is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_mmG22Ii1UhNHFxb251VVFWcllTbGc5R0QzdVNSMVBxc2hv